# Subsivison broke my texture, how do i solve this

Tags: modeling, texturing

Before subdivison
[image: before subdivison]

After subdivison
[image: After subdivison]

The subdivison surface broke the assigned texture, how do i make it look like how it was before sub surf while enabling sub surf

Comment: try to click on simple instead of catmull clark

Comment: Where is the texture you are talking about? I only see a Principled BSDF with no texture node plugged in. Also can you post a picture of how it looks like when it was not "broken"?

Comment: maybe you don't need a Subdivision Surface for this kind of object, maybe bevel the angles, shade smooth and enable Auto Smooth?

Comment: In **this** case planes don't need subdivisions.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I think he has assigned materials to different part of object. the face of table has that material of yellow color and so on. Instead of using subdiv add a bevel modifier. Or the best method apply the subdiv and again select the parts and assign material to that part.